# Different results for Bitmap.Maketransparent function

Tags: c#, image-processing, graphics, bitmap

My problem is that i want to make an image background transparent. And the following function works fine for me but while testing on a different machine I found out that there are a lot of artifact colors and the transparency is not as clear as it is on my machine and some other machines.
      I was working with the debug build and the test was done on release build. But even with release build we see different results on different machines.

```
Image CreateTransparentBackgroundImage(Image image)
        {
            using (Bitmap tempBitmap = new Bitmap(image.Width, image.Height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb))
            {
                var g = Graphics.FromImage(tempBitmap);
                Rectangle rec = new Rectangle(0 ,0,image.Width, image.Height);
                g.DrawImage(image,rec, 0, 0,image.Width,image.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
                tempBitmap.MakeTransparent(System.Drawing.Color.White);
                g.Dispose();
                return (Image)tempBitmap.Clone();
            }
        }
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Do you get the different results on the exact same source image?

Comment: Yes, the same image gives different results on different machines.

Comment: That sounds very strange. Can you post links to the Images or small examples that show the problem? (One source and two modified versions would be best..)

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bwjj96tG2KSiNmpnbmVMVTNja1E/view?usp=sharing   cant upload the real images but this is what happens with the above function (transparent on black background)

Comment: OK, the result contains black, various shades of white and a few fringe colors. The original should also help a lot to get closer to an explanation. Sorry if I am asking this once more: Are the machines using the same file or are they creating a source from the same process and the same sources? GDI+ should not create differing resilts imo. Is there a pattern, like at least some machines are getting the same results..?

Comment: Ok just dug into it. The files are created by a different program so the source files are not the same. But the images are exactly the same so this should work for all the cases ........right???? (P.S new to programming really appreciate the response :) )  BTW on my machine the results are always clear .

Comment: _the source files are not the same. But the images are exactly the same so this should work for all the cases ........right?_ Not necessarily. The MakeTransparent call will only work on exactly __one__ color. If you want white  (255,255,255) then (255,254,255) will not be processed event though they look exactly the same.  I suspect that this is the reason. So you probably should prefix the MakeTransparent witha routine that changes all almost white pixels to real white. If you want to I could write one in an answer..

Comment: Hm, come to think of it, instead of prefixing the MakeTransparent call, I guess the routine could include creating the transparency as well. I'll did up one of my solutions..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem seems to come from very slightly differing sources with very slight differences in the target color.

`MakeTransparent` doesn't provide for **any** tolerance.

Here is a function with the necessary tolerance. It will make every pixel transparent that is closer than `delta` to the target color. (The distance is the simple sum of the three channels' deltas..)

```
public static Bitmap MakeTransparent(Bitmap bmp, Color col, int delta)
{
    // we expect a 32bpp bitmap!
    var bmpData = bmp.LockBits(
                            new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height),
                            ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, bmp.PixelFormat);

    long len = bmpData.Height * bmpData.Stride;
    byte[] data = new byte[len];
    Marshal.Copy(bmpData.Scan0, data, 0, data.Length);

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i += 4)
    {
        int dist = Math.Abs(data[i + 0] - col.B);
        dist += Math.Abs(data[i + 1] - col.G);
        dist += Math.Abs(data[i + 2] - col.R);
        if (dist <= delta) data[i + 3] = 0;
    }
    Marshal.Copy(data, 0, bmpData.Scan0, data.Length);
    bmp.UnlockBits(bmpData);
    return bmp;
}
```

Here are four images: 1) the source you gave and 2) - 3) results of calling the function with deta values of 5, 10 and 50. I have put them on top of a solid red background so you can see the tranparent pixels..:

[image: four versions]

Comment: Thank you for this. Just a quick question shouldn't it be i+0, i+1, i+2 like that to get the values from all RGB so this works for all cases ?