# C# - Make Black Pixel of Image Transparent

Tags: c#, image, pixel

i am with a big problem.

I have a code to compare 2 image pixels. It look for the first image pixels within the second image pixel.

```
 private bool FindBitmap12(Bitmap bmpNeedle, Bitmap bmpHaystack, out Point location)
    {
        if (bmpNeedle == null || bmpHaystack == null)
        {
            location = new Point();
            return false;
        }
        for (int outerX = 0; outerX < bmpHaystack.Width - bmpNeedle.Width; outerX++)
        {
            for (int outerY = 0; outerY < bmpHaystack.Height - bmpNeedle.Height; outerY++)
            {
                for (int innerX = 0; innerX < bmpNeedle.Width; innerX++)
                {
                    for (int innerY = 0; innerY < bmpNeedle.Height; innerY++)
                    {
                        Color cNeedle = bmpNeedle.GetPixel(innerX, innerY);
                        Color cHaystack = bmpHaystack.GetPixel(innerX + outerX, innerY + outerY);
                        if (cNeedle.R != cHaystack.R || cNeedle.G != cHaystack.G || cNeedle.B != cHaystack.B)
                        {
                            goto notFound;
                        }
                    }
                }
                location = new Point(outerX, outerY);
                return true;
            notFound:
                continue;
            }
        }
        location = Point.Empty;
        return false;
    }
```

The code above work perfect.

The problem is that now i need to compare a picture that have black pixels on it whitin a picture that do not have black pixels. So what happens is that the code above return that the pictures are different.

So i thought: hey, lets make this black pixels transparent!

I maded this code:

```
Rectangle mouseNewRect = new Rectangle(new Point(x - 125, y - 125), new Size(250, 250));
Bitmap myBitmap2 = new Bitmap(mouseNewRect.Width, mouseNewRect.Height);
Bitmap myBitmap3 = new Bitmap("Images\\xd1.png");
myBitmap3.MakeTransparent(Color.Black);
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(myBitmap2);
g.CopyFromScreen(mouseNewRect.Left, mouseNewRect.Top, 0, 0, myBitmap2.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);
```

myBitmap2 == the big picture;

myBitmap3 == the picture that have black pixels that will be compared within myBitmap2.

So as you guys see, i maded myBitmap3 black pixels transparent, so when the myBitmap3 are compared with myBitmap2, the result should be: hey, we found the pixels of myBitmap3 inside myBitmap2!

I dont know why, but even making black pixels transparent, the result of :

```
bool sucess2 = FindBitmap12(myBitmap3, myBitmap2, out location);
```

== false. So i am making black pixels transparent but somehow, sucess2 == false.

I tried delete the black pixels on https://pixlr.com, leaving a "blank" space in this black pixes, but also the result of sucess2 == false.

Some1 have any idea of how to remove this black pixels of myBitmap3?

Thanks.

EDIT: in this part:

```
Color cNeedle = bmpNeedle.GetPixel(innerX, innerY);
Color cHaystack = bmpHaystack.GetPixel(innerX + outerX, innerY + outerY);
if (cNeedle.R != cHaystack.R || cNeedle.G != cHaystack.G || cNeedle.B != cHaystack.B)
                        {
                            goto notFound;
                        }
```

Maybe i can make a "If" that if find a black pixel, ignore it and continue the search as this black pixel do not exist?

Comment: Isn't this a repost? I had commented, given you advice and a link, you didn't answer and simply deleted the question?

Comment: Hey @TaW, this post is with full problem, all codes are here. Sorry for that, didnt see your answer

Comment: You should still be able to recover my comment.

Comment: @TaW, can't, post are deleted... can you repost it if possible?

Comment: We don't know anything about your image so we can only guess. MakeTransparent will only make __one__ color transparent, no slack. So if your pixels are even a little bit off as they always are in jpg and when having anti-aliasing it will miss many pixels. Instead calculate the difference and compare to a delta! - [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28477781/different-results-for-bitmap-maketransparent-function/28501183?s=2|34.5759#28501183) is a routine that does something very similar.

Answer (score -1):

Without diving deep [into the API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa327158(v=vs.71).aspx) I assume that the MakeTransparent method doesn't change the pixel's RGB values. It just sets somewhere in the palette and information, that this particular color shouldn't be drawn on the screen. This is why when you compare the RGB values they are still the same.

I didn't test or validate my answer, but this would be my assumption working a while with images.

If I'm right the simplest approach might be to only compare the pixel if it isn't marked as transparent color in the palette.

**UPDATE**

There doesn't seem to be a simple way of checking the system palette. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/gdi/system-palette

Instead: Could you try to compare the alpha component of the pixel? If you have set the pixel's alpha value (via pixlr/gimp/photoshop) to transparent it should be of value 0. So your code would be:

```
Color cNeedle = bmpNeedle.GetPixel(innerX, innerY);
Color cHaystack = bmpHaystack.GetPixel(innerX + outerX, innerY + outerY);

bool isDifferentRGB = cNeedle.R != cHaystack.R || cNeedle.G != cHaystack.G || cNeedle.B != cHaystack.B;
bool isTransparent = cNeedle.A == 0;

if (isDifferentRGB && !isTransparent)
{
     goto notFound;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! How can i compare the pixel if it isn't marked as transparent color in the palette?